# Parallel for long running filter

Tags: shell-script, gnu-parallel

I am scraping phone numbers from a certain list of web pages and have implemented map-reduce as:

```
PARALLEL_OPTS="..."
SCRIPT="curl --silent --cookie '$COOKIES' {} | egrep -o '[2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' | sort -u"
cat URLS | parallel $PARALLEL_OPTS "$SCRIPT" >> numbers
```

This is inefficient because the URLs are on the same server and each invocation of `curl` uses a new connection. Instead I would like to reuse connections (HTTP keep-alive) like:

```
cat URLs | wget -q --input-file=- --output-document=- 2>/dev/null
```

Is there a way to run `parallel` that uses one process and passes work through STDIN, rather than multiple invocations with arguments?

Comment: Divide your list in, say, 8 sublists based on the first digit, then run 8 copies of `wget`.  Forget about `parallel`.

Comment: Needs to be automated and scaleable.

Comment: Then find a better way to divide the list.  There is nothing there that prevents automation.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
PARALLEL_OPTS="..."
```

If you instead use $PARALLEL, GNU Parallel will pick those up automatically.

You are looking for `--pipe`. Here we give `wget` 1000 urls at a time:

```
cat URLS | parallel --pipe -n 1000 wget -q --input-file=- --output-document=- '2>/dev/null'
```

It is, however, a bit more efficient not to count lines, but instead just give a block of URLs (1 MB is the default):

```
cat URLS | parallel --pipe --block 1M wget -q --input-file=- --output-document=- '2>/dev/null'
```

This maxes out at around 1 GB/s. For your use it is most likely enough (who processes more than 1 GB of URLs per second?), but the day you need more speed, this is the highly efficient way (e.g. useful when you have TBs of data):

```
parallel -a URLS --pipepart --roundrobin my_command
```

It can deliver 1 GB/s per core. Available from version 20150922.

Consider walking through the tutorial once a year `man parallel_tutorial`. Your command line will love you for it.